# Can Lightning Rush also trigger an Opportunity Attack on the triggering enemy?

Tags: dnd-4e

Lightning Rush:

> At-Will        Augmentable, Psionic, Weapon
>
> Immediate Interrupt      Melee 1
>
> Trigger: An enemy within 5 squares of you targets an ally with an attack
>
> Effect: Before the attack, you move your speed to a square adjacent to the triggering enemy.
>
> Target: The triggering enemy
>
> Attack: Constitution vs. AC
>   Hit: 1[W] + Constitution modifier damage.
>   Effect: You don’t get your normal standard action on your next turn.
>
> *snip
>
> Augment 2
>   Hit: 2[W] + Constitution modifier damage, and you become the target of the triggering attack.
>   Effect: You get your normal standard action on your next turn.

So, an enemy makes a ranged or area attack.  You interrupt with either the unaugmented power or the A2 version (I've elided the A1 version because it's a minor modification on the unaugmented one).  You move your speed to a square adjacent to the triggering enemy.  Do you also get an OA against the triggering enemy?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Lightning Rush is an Immediate Interrupt that happens *before* the attack, so the condition for an opportunity attack is met when the attack happens (and so you get another attack before the attack).

So yes, you can perform both an immediate interrupt and an opportunity action against the same attack.

Similar situation is a fighter whose mark is standing next to him and makes a ranged attack against someone else. The fighter could take both the opportunity attack and also his immediate interrupt from Combat Challenge.

Comment: Right, but the Fighter is already adjacent to the enemy.  The RC defined OAs as taking place when an enemy uses a Ranged or Area attack power- does the Battlemind actually get adjacent before that trigger?

Comment: @JLan yes, she does.